# Do not rotate label in before

Tags: css

I have before like below and I want rotate just background not label.

How I can do it ?

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ff756b;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

div::before {
  content: 'lable';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -33px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 3px 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: why are you rotating the :before

Comment: @AmanSharma for create shape that I show in the snippet with before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `:after` with `div` and add `content`

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ff756b;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
div:after {
  content: 'Lable';
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -29px;
  color: #fff;
 }
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -33px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 3px 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    transform: rotate (45deg);
```

Will rotate the complete element, including content and background.

If you want to rotate only the background then you need to keep the background separate or you can add your label in actual element instead of pseudo-element.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted solution, or if it added any value but didn't solve your problem completely you can simply upvote the answer.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text into an after pseudo element which is not rotated.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ff756b;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -33px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 3px 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div::after {
  content: 'lable';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

However, be aware of accessibility issues. That text may not get read out by a screen reader and if it is important for the user to know it is there is may be better to put the text in a label element actually within the HTML. You can still style it the same way so it is within the red 'bubble'.